# How can I create a short cut to a directory on a Windows Phone device?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

When I plug in my Windows Phone it appears in My Computer as a portable device but the data I need regular access to is many sub directories in. Is it possible to create a short cut or access a path on a mobile device directly?

When I open the properties of the folder I want it says the location starts with "Computer\Name of Phone\Phone\". The problem is using that as a path to navigate straight to the files doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like this has more to do with your PC than the phone itself. Potentially needs to be moved to SE SuperUser. What is your PC operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mapping a short cut on a PC (should probably go on SuperUser).

Comment: I think it is fine because it requires a Windows Phone device and it is a question that deals with how to a PC in conjunction with a phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone connects to Windows via MTP ([Media Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)) and not via MSC. MSC-devices ([Mass Storage Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_storage)) showing up as removal drives with a drive letter, MTP does not. So, you can't create a shortcut.